# z-index of container div disabling contained links

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

## My problem:

I have a parent `div` set to `z-index:0` but as an unwanted side-effect, two of the links contained within the parent `div` are disabled (no hover, no link action).

## Context:

I'm using an image slider (Nivo Slider). I've had to set the `z-index` to `0` to allow my navigation menu to correctly overlay the image slider. The next and previous links no longer function when I change the `z-index` of the parent container.

## Live example:

http://tinyurl.com/boej3sq

- `div.nivoSlider` = **parent container**
- `a.nivo-prevNav` / `a.nivo-nextNav` = **problematic links**

## My question:

How do I fix the "broken" links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your live example, the nivo-controlNav div is actually covering your previous and next links (hope that is what you are talking about)  You will notice if you go to the very top of the next and previous buttons that you can press them, but if you go to the middle of the button you can not.   What I would do is set a width of 50% or a fixed width on nivo-controlNav so that it pulls the right side away from your links.

Alternative: you can increase the z-index on nivo-directionNav (not z-indexed so probably why its getting overlayed) or links

Comment: most browsers have an inspect element option if you right click on the element in question, its an easy way to diagnose z-indexing problems

Comment: Much thanks. I've opted for specifying the width to 50%. The alternative, as suggested by Self Taught Programmer, introduced a myriad of other styling conundrums related to positioning. Thanks again.

Comment: my pleasure, glad I could help... great looking site by the way

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can get rid of the 'z-index:0' on the parent element.

Or,

The long route where you can put 'position:relative' on the child elements and re-style the button according to the look it has now. Z-index works with parent and child element by way of the position property.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer and for educating me on the relationship between z-index and position:relative. I've opted for gingabox's answer because it doesn't require extensive restyling of the slider.